# Why do I get the same value in every row for my SSRS matrix?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-tablix

I have read a number of tutorials on how to do this, and I am following them, but I am not getting the results I expect and I don't know why.

There are multiple types of Programs, and they all occur multiple times in the data with different amounts. The data looks like:
**Program           |  Amount**
Consumer Affairs  |  23
Crime             |  2
Consumer Affairs  |  43
Consumer Affairs  |  12
Licences          |  35
Crime             |  51
etc....

I want to group by the Program and show the total Amount for that program. I have added the Program as a row group to my matrix, and added the Amount as the rows and "summarize by" SUM.

I want to display:

Program             | Amount

Consumer Affairs    | 500

Crime               | 675

Licenses            | 345

However what I am getting is just the total of all amounts repeated in the Amount column:

Program           | Amount

Consumer Affairs    | 1520

Crime               | 1520

Licenses            | 1520

All the tutorials say add a row group for Program, and then drag the Amount into the next space to the right of Program and then summarize it by sum. I am doing this but it's like the sum is outside of the group and I can't figure out how to change this.
[image: This is how I've set it up, and it's not working as expected]

Answer (score 0):

The answer was that my data was coming from an SSAS model, and the Amount was a column in this model and not a measure of the sum of the Amount. The SSRS matrix would only aggergate if the Amount came from a measure I'd pre-defined in the tabular model as Amount_Total := Sum(Amount). Once I used this measure as the value to drop into the matrix and not the column with the Amount data, the matrix automatically applied the SUM function to is according to all the tutorials.